# Best practice for placement of large test datasets?

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, dataset, integration-testing

I'm dealing with an enormous amount of data (say, video) and most integration tests require at least a decent subset of this data.

These test files (subsets) can range from 200MB to 2GB.

Where would be a good place to put these files?  Ideally they would not go directly into our version control system because people shouldn't have to download 5GB+ of test data every time they want to check out the project.

The test data needs to be updated by Jenkins whenever a schema change occurs (we already have this part figured out), so either maven or svn would need to download the latest version if anybody wanted to run the integration tests.

It would be great if it could be on-demand since we never run all the tests at once locally (e.g., if we are running TestX, then download the files required for this test before running).

Does anybody have any suggestion(s) on how to approach this?

**Edit** -- For the sake of simplicity let's say that the test files are incompressible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I would setup a file server share, that contains all the test data in a nicely organized way. Then let your test download the necessary test data itself. The advantage is that you can update the test data in the central place without updating the tests themselves. The next time the tests run, the new testdata will be downloaded.

If you need versioning, you would could use a repository manager like Nexus instead of a simple filesystem. If you need audit-ability, I would suggest a repository manager like subversion. However, make sure that you use a separate repo just for your testdata, so you can easily clean out the repo by replacing it with an empty repo that gets only the newest testdata loaded.

Comment: Forgot to accept this; we ended up putting all the data on a NAS.